# Retrieve both corrected data and error message with Zod

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, parsing, zod

I am working with Zod for schema validation and I'm attempting to retrieve both the corrected data and error messages when a validation fails. Let me illustrate with a simplified example.

Given this schema:

```js
const testSchema = z.number().min(0).array();
const test = testSchema.safeParse([1, -1]);
```

I can retrieve the error message using:

```js
console.log(test.error.flatten());
// Expected output:
// {
//   formErrors: [],
//   fieldErrors: { '1': [ 'Number must be greater than or equal to 0' ] }
// }
```

However, when I attempt to catch the error and provide corrected data:

```js
const testSchema = z.number().min(0).catch(0).array();
const test = testSchema.safeParse([1, -1]);
```

The error will disappear and the result will be as follows:

```js
console.log(test.data); // Expected output: [1, 0]
```

How can I adjust my schema or input parsing to obtain both the corrected data and the associated error messages when validation fails?

---

I experimented with the pipe function to achieve this. However, it doesn't seem related to the result I want to achieve.

I expected to get both the corrected data (like `[1, 0]`) and the associated error messages (such as `{ '1': [ 'Number must be greater than or equal to 0' ] }`).